# Qt Creator can't build debugger helper

Tags: qt, clang++

I asked this question on the Qt forums, but they seem to be pretty quiet these days.

I'm running the relatively new Qt Creator 2.6.2 (with Qt 5.0.1). When I try to build the debugger helper, I get the following error:

> Building helper(s) with toolchain 'GCC (x86 64bit)'... Building helper
>   'GDB helper' in
>   /Developer/Applications/Qt/5.0.1/clang_64//qtc-debugging-helper/
>
> Running /Developer/Applications/Qt/5.0.1/clang_64/bin/qmake -spec
>   macx-clang dumper.pro -nocache CONFIG+=x86_64 ...
>
> Running /usr/bin/make all -k ... Error running '/usr/bin/make all -k'
>   in /Developer/Applications/Qt/5.0.1/clang_64//qtc-debugging-helper/:
>   The process returned exit code 2: clang++ -c -pipe
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -O2 -Wall -W -fPIC -DUSE_QT_CORE=1 -DUSE_QT_GUI=1 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../mkspecs/macx-clang -I. -I../include -I../include/QtWidgets -I../lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I../include/QtGui -I../lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I../include/QtCore -I../lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -o dumper.o dumper.cpp make: clang++: No such file or directory make: ***
>   [dumper.o] Error 1 make: Target `all' not remade because of errors.
>   Build failed.

So, I see that it's looking for a file called "clang++" which I evidently don't have. Can someone explain to me what the workaround for this is? I'm accustomed to just using the pre-built install packages for Qt.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install command line tools package for Xcode which includes 'clang++' compiler.

You can find them [here](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) under `Looking for additional developer tools?` link.

Comment: Ah. It appears that I can't install the new version of XCode over 10.6. As luck would have it, I just ordered 10.7 yesterday and should have it very soon. When I get it, I'll follow your instructions and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Your advice fixed the stated problem -- I can now build the debugger helper. Unfortunately, I *still* can't view vectors in the debugger in a helpful way. Aargh.

Comment: @mzimmers Unfortunately, I can't help you with that, because I only have knowledge to recompile something on OS X. However, you should ask new question, and it is likely to someone answer you!